# Minitest `assert_output` incorrect check for stderr

Tags: ruby, minitest, stderr

I need to write some tests for check output to STDERR by minitest
It works fine, if I want to check output to STDOUT, but if try check STDERR - asser_output simply not catch any string in it

So my code looks like this:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

class OutputTest < MiniTest::Test
  def test_output_stdout
    assert_output(/Test/, '') {puts 'Test'}
  end

  def test_output_stderr
    assert_output('', /Test/) {STDERR.puts 'Test'}
  end
end
```

And it gives me error:

```
 1) Failure:
OutputTest#test_output_stderr [test/assert_test.rb:9]:
In stderr.
Expected /Test/ to match "".

2 runs, 4 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

From `assert_output` [documentation](http://docs.seattlerb.org/minitest/Minitest/Assertions.html#method-i-assert_output) second argument of this method is pattern to check of STDERR, but it's not working.
What I did wrong?

Comment: Instead of `STDERR.puts` you can use simply `warn` which should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works if you use `$stderr` instead of `STDERR`:

```
assert_output('', /Test/) { $stderr.puts 'Test' }
```

Internally, `assert_output` uses the [capture_io](http://docs.seattlerb.org/minitest/Minitest/Assertions.html#method-i-capture_io) helper. This swaps `$stdout` and `$stderr` with two StringIO, yields the block, and swaps the `$stdout` and `$stderr` back. This is possible because `$stdout` and `$stderr` are variables.

`STDOUT` and `STDERR` are constants defined on the [Object](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html) class. Thus they can not be swapped like `$stdout` and `$stderr`. When doing `STDERR.puts`, the output is not captured by minitest helpers and the assertion fails.